# How to reduce memory usage of spaCy lemmatization?

Tags: python, memory, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I am relatively new to spaCy, and I am trying to tokenize + lemmatize 200 MB of text for an NLP project.

I first tried `nlp = spacy.load('en')` which resulted in a `MemoryError`.

After doing some research, I tried `nlp = spacy.blank('en')` to eliminate unnecessary functionality but it is still taking all 16 GB of my memory (and eventually resulting in `MemoryError`). This seems excessive to me.

What can I do to reduce the memory usage of spaCy or is it not possible? Thank you!

Original code:

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
train['spacy_tokens'] = train['text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))

def lemmatize(x):
    intermediate_lemmas = [token.lemma_.lower() for token in x
            if not token.is_punct]
    return [lemma for lemma in intermediate_lemmas
           if lemma not in stop_words
           and lemma != "-PRON-"
           and lemma != " "
           ]

train['lemmas'] = train['spacy_tokens'].apply(lambda x: lemmatize(x))
print(train.head())
```

Comment: 200 MB should not be a problem, can you post the original error message? Plus the code you ran?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. When processing loads of data, memory consumption may become an issue with spaCy. But just running `spacy.load('en')` once should not be a problem and should not consume that much memory. Try reinstalling spacy and the models (preferably in a new venv).